# Deleting in chunks with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a large amount of data from my AWS RDS MySQL instance in chunks. I'm trying to adapt the code found in this [link](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks), but I'm stuck with a syntax error I cannot fix.

**Error:**

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'main1: LOOP
    SELECT @z := operation_id FROM operations_test WHERE operation_id' at line 2
```

**Code:**

```
SET @apt = 'DTW'; 

SET @a = (SELECT MIN(operation_id) FROM operations_test);

BEGIN
    main1: LOOP
        SELECT @z := operation_id FROM operations_test WHERE operation_id >= @a ORDER BY operation_id LIMIT 1000,1;
        IF @z IS NULL THEN
          LEAVE main1;  -- last chunk
       END IF;
       DELETE operations_test, profiles_test FROM profiles_test LEFT JOIN operations_test ON operations_test.operation_id=profiles_test.operation_id WHERE operations_test.airport_id = @apt
            AND operations_test.operation_id >= @a
             AND operations_test.operation_id <  @z;
       DELETE operations_test FROM operations_test WHERE airport_id = @apt
            AND operation_id >= @a
             AND operation_id <  @z;
       SET @a = @z;
        SLEEP 1;  -- be a nice guy, especially in replication
    END LOOP main1;
END;
# Last chunk:
DELETE operations_test, profiles_test FROM profiles_test LEFT JOIN operations_test ON operations_test.operation_id=profiles_test.operation_id WHERE operations_test.airport_id = @apt
    AND id >= @a;
DELETE operations_test FROM operations_test WHERE airport_id = @apt
    AND id >= @a;
```

Comment: You might need to set a different delimiter before declaring the anonymous block. Something like `DELIMITER $$ BEGIN ... END; DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BEGIN ... END` and `LOOP` statements are only valid in the context of a MySQL stored program (e.g. a `PROCEDURE`, `FUNCTION`, `TRIGGER`, )

As an example of usage:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo 
BEGIN 
   SET ... ;
   SET ... ; 
   myloop: LOOP 
     ...
   END LOOP myloop;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Given that we don't see a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, we're going to guess that the error message is the result of executing this as a bare statement. A syntax error is the expected result.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html

Comment: @RickJames:  OP is following example, there's no indication on the page that the syntax is valid only in the context of a MySQL stored program. http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks